# Finding Column Headers Associated with Row Totals

Tags: excel

I have a table of data that looks similar to the table below:

```
N   A  B  C  Total
n1  5          5
n2        8    8
n3     3       3
```

I currently have a VLOOKUP  set up so that I can look for an n1,n2... etc and get their corresponding total, which is always equal to the total of one of A,B,C.  That is, any n can only have one of A,B,C filled in.  Now, I would like to also have a function that returns in an adjacent column the 'bucket' that the total corresponds to.  This because the calculation I would like to do corresponding to each total will change depending on what the column header or 'bucket' is.  Is there an easy way to set this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one in `H2`:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(9E+307,INDEX($B$2:$D$4,MATCH(G2,$A$2:$A$4,0),0)))
```

[image]

**Explanation:**

- part `MATCH(G2,$A$2:$A$4,0)` gives you index of `n2` (value from `G2`) in range `$A$2:$A$4` - returns 2
- part `INDEX($B$2:$D$4,MATCH(G2,$A$2:$A$4,0),0)` - gets address of row where `n2` is found - returns `B3:D3`
- part `MATCH(9E+307,...)` returns index of last non empty cell in range `B3:D3` (based on *any n can only have one of A,B,C filled in*)
- and finally, `INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(9E+307,...))` returns corresponding bucket

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out, is there a reason your match value is 9E+307?

Comment: yeah, it's special trick. `9E+307` is almost the biggest value avaliable in excel, so `MATCH(9E+307,...)` returns index of last non empty cell in range `B3:D3` - see my updated answer for more detailed explanatoin

Comment: So for example if the real cells were I5 to L5 (and down the rows for each n) I would still match 9E+307?

Comment: yes, just leave as it is now. It doesn't depend on any other parts of formula

Comment: Thanks, I'm just sorting out some small bugs with my application of it, at the moment, n3, say, is spitting out column C instead of B as the corresponding column.

Comment: if you can share your workbook somewhere (say in https://www.dropbox.com) I can help you to figure out what is wrong

Comment: Thanks for the offer, it was just a silly error on my part.  Your response provided a perfect walkthrough!